# Expert Pdf - add footer on all pages except on the first page

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I am using Expert PDF to generate PDF from HTML.
I have to generate footer on all pages except on the first page.
I tried with:

```
PdfConverter pdfConverter = new PdfConverter();
AddFooter(pdfConverter);

private void AddFooter(PdfConverter pdfConverter)
{
    string thisPageURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
    string headerAndFooterHtmlUrl = thisPageURL.Substring(0, thisPageURL.LastIndexOf('/')) + "/HeaderAndFooterHtml.htm";

    //enable footer
    pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.ShowFooter = true;
    // set the footer height in points
    pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.FooterHeight = 60;
    //write the page number
    pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.TextArea = new TextArea(0, 30, "This is page &p; of &P;  ",
        new System.Drawing.Font(new System.Drawing.FontFamily("Times New Roman"), 10, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point));
    pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.TextArea.EmbedTextFont = true;
    pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.TextArea.TextAlign = HorizontalTextAlign.Right;
    // set the footer HTML area
    pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.HtmlToPdfArea = new HtmlToPdfArea(0, 0, -1, pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.FooterHeight,
                headerAndFooterHtmlUrl, 1024, -1);
    pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.HtmlToPdfArea.FitHeight = true;
}
```

but this code generate footer on all pages. 
Can someone give me idea or solution for this problem? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where can be pdfConverter Class can be found? I need it for my project.

Comment: Check the library https://www.html-to-pdf.net/docs/html-to-pdf-library/html/T_ExpertPdf_HtmlToPdf_PdfConverter.htm

Comment: Sorry, I should have asked before, but is this can be used in JAVA?

Comment: Unfortunately no because expert PDF is based on Microsoft .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below line in your code:

```
pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.ShowOnFirstPage = false;
```